# php server method sends GET instead of DELETE

Tags: php, html, rest, http, http-delete

I am trying to implement a basic user registration RESTful api.
I have a html form registerform.html, deregisterform.html, users.php, register.php and deregister.php which are all pasted below.

When i visit the registerform.html in my browser, i can fill in the details and a POST request is received by the users.php script and a json response is echoed back showing the id number of the user thats just been added.
My problem is that when i use the deregister form, the users.php script should recive a DELETE request, but is actually getting a GET request. I've been looking for an answer to this problem but im not finding a solution.

registerform.html

```html
<form action="users.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
    FirstName: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
    Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="dob" /><br />
    Telephone: <input type="mob" name="tel" /><br />
    Email: <input type="email" name="email1" /><br />
    Confirm Email: <input type="email" name="email2" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name ="pass2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="sub" />
    
    <br/><A HREF="login.php">Already Registered? Login Here</A><br/>
</form>
```

deregisterform.html

```html
<form action="users.php" method="DELETE">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name ="pass2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Deregister" name="sub" />
</form>
```

register.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['uname']) &&  isset($_POST['fname']) &&  isset($_POST['lname']) &&  isset($_POST['tel']) &&  isset($_POST['dob']) &&  
isset($_POST['email1']) &&  isset($_POST['email2']) &&  isset($_POST['pass1']) &&  isset($_POST['pass2'])) 
    {
        //take values from http POST and trim whitespace
        $uname = trim($_POST['uname']);
        $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
        $tel = trim($_POST['tel']);
        $dob = trim($_POST['dob']);
        $email1 = trim($_POST['email1']);
        $email2 = trim($_POST['email2']);
        $pass1 = trim($_POST['pass1']);
        $pass2 = trim($_POST['pass2']);
        //validate the data from the form
        if($um->isNameFormatted($uname))
        {
            if(!$um->isUserExists($uname)) //does user already exist with this username?
            {
                if($um->isNameFormatted($fname)) //first name formatted correctly
                {
                    if($um->isNameFormatted($lname)) //last name formatted correctly
                    {
                        if($um->isDOBFormatted($dob))
                        {
                            if($email1 == $email2)
                            {
                                if($pass1 == $pass2)
                                {
                                    if($um->isPasswordClean($pass1))
                                    {
                                        if($um->isTelephoneVerified($tel))
                                        {
                                            //everything is OKAY --- PROCEED WITH ADDING USER
                                            $user = $um->registerUser($uname,$fname,$lname,$dob,$tel,$email1,$pass1);
                                            if(isset($user))///
                                            {
                                                //successful registration
                                                $response["error"] = false;
                                                $response["id"] = $user;
                                                echo json_encode($response);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }?>
```

deregister.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pass1'] && isset($_POST['pass2'])
{
  $uname = $_POST['uname'];
  $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
  $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
  if($um->isUserExists($uname))
  {
    if($pass1 == $pass2)
    {
      if(true)//$um->isPasswordFor($uname, $pass))
      {
        $um->deregisterUser($uname, $pass1);
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["text"] = "User removed!";
                echo json_encode($response);
      } 
      else
      {
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["text"] = "Wrong username and password combination!";
                echo json_encode($response);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $response["error"] = true;
      $response["text"] = "Passwords don't match!";
      echo json_encode($response);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["text"] = "User(".$uname.") not in database!";
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
}?>
```

users.php

```
<?php
error_reporting( -1 );
require('userManagement.php');
$um = new UserManagement();
$response = array("error" => FALSE);
//check if user logged in and authenticated
if(true)
{
    echo "user logged in.";
    echo $httpVerb = trim(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']));
    switch($httpVerb)
    {
        case "GET":
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["httpVerb"] = $httpVerb;
            echo json_encode($response);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["httpVerb"] = $httpVerb;
            echo json_encode($response);
            break;
        case "POST":
           include('register.php');     
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            include('deregister.php');
            break;
        default:
            echo "http verb ".$httpVerb." is not supported for this resource.";
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["httpVerb"] = $httpVerb;
            echo json_encode($response);
            break;
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "need to login first.";
}?>
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3 for valid form action values.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `DELETE` as a form action.

From the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-action), we have:

> The `method` and `formmethod` content attributes are enumerated attributes
>   with the following keywords and states:
>
> - The keyword `get`, mapping to the state **GET**, indicating the HTTP GET method.
> - The keyword `post`, mapping to the state **POST**, indicating the HTTP POST method.
>
> **The invalid value default for these attributes is the GET state.**

Comment: so...would i maybe put a hidden field in the form? something like 'httpVerb' and test the value of this instead?

Comment: @gezinspace you can use DELETE through ajax.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name ="_method" value="DELETE" />` @gezinspace

Comment: Do as @samayo suggested

Comment: Yep, exactly as @samayo said.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo as I said, you can't use it as a form action, but it is a valid HTTP METHOD, of course

Comment: ... And filter the http verb inside your logic. `if($_POST['_method'] === 'DELETE')` for example.

Comment: @Berriel I know that.. I only said, that other HTTP methods are available using ajax.

Comment: okay thanks guys. so if someone sends a http delete from curl, it isnt going to send the response i want? presumably

Comment: You can create another conditional. `if($_POST['_method'] === 'DELETE' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE')`.

Comment: @berriel...is there anyway i can make it respond properly to a delete request  because anyone using the api shouldnt need to be concerned with testing for the presense of a hidden field

Comment: @gezinspace If someone sends a request using curl or AJAX, with the DELETE method, your script might work.